# Sass inside .html file throwing errors on VsCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, sass, electron

I'm working with an Electron app that reads this "unusual" html file that contains the Sass inside a custom tag that is read and processed on the Electron app. The compiling from Sass to CSS is done on this Electron app, where it grabs the HTML and the Sass separately, so far so good.

What I couldn't figure out is how to make VS code linter to stop making those red lines when I use the Sass syntax instead of CSS. I could only think that is because I'm using Sass inside an HTML file, can anyone attest that this is true? How could I disable this verification on VS code so it stops saying my Sass code is not valid?